# How to get email/data of a user who signed-in Code Igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created system where a user can sign-up and then sign-in using Code Igniter
My question is how can i get the email  of the person who signs in the system.

I have used session like this

```
$email=$this->session->userdata('email');

//a db query using the email obtained via session  
$query=$this->db->select('*')->from('referral')->where('referral_email',$email)->get();
```

However, i don't think this is the most secure way or effective way doing it.
  Is there a better/secure way to accomplish this task.
Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is secure as long as you are storing your active sessions in the database.

go to the `application/config/config.php` and enable the ci_sessions table

you also need to create the ci_sessions table in your database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

The way that database sessions work is that they save a unique cookie with the session ID, this session ID is the identifier to the table row where all of the userdata is stored. So the client never gets to see or modify the data.

I hope that answers your question =]

Comment: Wow am impressed with myself. Thanks for the confirmation @josue